# python showing this TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python

I'm running this python Code in Kali Terminal and facing this problem.
[I found this code in Github](https://github.com/cyberboysumanjay/TorrFlix)

This script download movies from torrent and it uses WebTorrent API
Once I used this script in windows it was working without any error but when I switch to *kali linux* and try to run this script I'm facing this error.

I'm not very much familiar with python

**Here is my Code**

```
import requests
import subprocess
import sys

def main():
    movie_name = input("Enter the movie name:\n")
    print(f"Searching for {movie_name}")
    base_url = f"https://api.sumanjay.cf/torrent/?query={movie_name}"
    torrent_results = requests.get(url=base_url).json()
    index = 1
    magnet = []
    for result in torrent_results:
        if 'movie' in result['type'].lower():
            print(index, ") ", result['name'], "-->", result['size'])
            index += 1
            magnet.append(result['magnet'])
    if magnet:
        choice = int(
            input("Enter the index of the movie which you want to stream\n"))
        try:
            magnet_link = magnet[choice-1]
            download = False  # Default is streaming
            stream_choice = int(
                input("Press 1 to stream or Press 2 to download the movie\n"))
            if stream_choice == 2:
                download = True

            webtorrent_stream(magnet_link, download)
        except IndexError:
            print("Incorrect Index entered")
    else:
        print(f"No results found for {movie_name}")

# Handle Streaming


def webtorrent_stream(magnet_link: str, download: bool):
    cmd = []
    cmd.append("webtorrent")
    cmd.append(magnet_link)
    if not download:
        cmd.append('--vlc')

    if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        subprocess.call(cmd)
    elif sys.platform.startswith('win32'):
        subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Error**

```
Enter the movie name:
Baby Boss
Searching for Baby Boss
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shiva/Desktop/TorrFlix/play.py", line 61, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/shiva/Desktop/TorrFlix/play.py", line 23, in main
    if 'movie' in result['type'].lower():
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Check my code and I run this code in windows it's working.

Comment: `torrent_result` contains `{'message': 'API is Down!', 'status': False}`

Comment: `torent_results` is a `dict` and `for result in torrent_results:` enumerates its keys which are the strings "message" and "status". I'm really curious what the working Windows implementation gets as `torent_results`. Is it a list of dicts? Can you post a sample? My guess is that you need to set a different user agent for the request.... not sure.

Comment: no! it's is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API is down currently that's why it is returning `{'message': 'API is Down!', 'status': False}` as response instead of expected movie data. Which is the  cause of the error.

Comment: But that should raise a ```TypeError```, not ```TypeError: string indices must be integers```

Comment: how to make this API? I need to run this help me out.

Comment: yes if API was down then It should not work in windows but it's working why?

Comment: @nishant Have you tried this api in windows recently? If not please do, it shouldn't work there too.

Comment: what ? It was working but leave it now what can I do help me out !

Comment: And it will work install all requirements for it in windows from here 
 https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent-cli